# How to remove part of image containing text in opencv

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

What method can I use in opencv to remove the black section containing text at the bottom of the image?

[image]

Any help appreciated

Comment: If it's always constant, just crop off the bottom 100 or so pixels.

Answer (score 0):

if Blender's suggestion does not work in your case, you can:

1. Threshold the image so that all pixels higher than 0 will become 255.
2. Find contours.
3. Calculate a bounding rectangle for each contour.
4. Define the largest bounding rectangle as the region to be kept (the other ones are just the letters). You can then simply use the found rectangle as a ROI.

Good luck,